MatPlotLib and Pip not Working in Python VSCode
I'm working on a Python code in VSCode and everytime I try to run it, no plot shows.
I get this error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
However, I checked the version, as I know I have this downloaded, and this is what my system says
import matplotlib
print('matplotlib: {}'.format(matplotlib.__version__))

results in
Python 3.9.6 (default, Aug  9 2024, 14:24:13)
[Clang 16.0.0 (clang-1600.0.26.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

So I went to re-install it to see if that helped out, but then I get an error that pip isn't installed.
This is the error
zsh: command not found: pip
Now, I also know that I have pip installed. So I checked the version of that, but somehow it isn't finding it. So I tried to install it again but I'm getting this error.
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.13/3.13.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/Users/(myname)/get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
I just updated my Mac to the newest software, so I think something happened with that. But I know these things are on my computer and work, as I used them about a week ago.
Can someone help me figure out what's going on here?
I was expecting my code to run, but many things are not being found on my system.

Check that Python configuration in VSCode is correct, and you better work with Python environments in VS Code rather than system-wide installation.
